# bash + Is there something like log4j for bash script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ksh

Is there something like **log4j** for bash script?

I know, I can just write a function , that write to log as the following example:

```
LOG ()  { 
           echo `date` $* >> /var/log/my_log.log 
        }
```

But actually I want to know if something like log4j is relevant for bash

in order to get the ability for – **error level** and etc

Comment: you could make separate logWarn/logError/.. functions that will depending on a variabele. Ypu might also use different logfiles, start any script with including mylog4j.bash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at `man logger`. It's an interface to the syslog system log module.

Comment: yes , but for example if I write:  logger ls , then this will written in the /var/log/messages , and I want seperate LOG file ( messages include all system logs )

Comment: second I want this format for example $date INFO/ERROR/DEBUG $DETAILS , etc

Comment: If you want a specific format probably the best solution is to write your own logging functions. If you accept the format provided by syslog, you can still use `logger` in bash with the `-p` option to set the priority but to choose the directories in which you want to save the logs you have to modify syslog.conf. By modifying syslog.conf you can, for example, set directory1 as the directory in which you save the logs with priority 1. You can set directory2 as the directory in which you save the logs with priority 2 and so on...

Answer (score 0):

There's good amount of detail on logging for shell scripts via global varaibles of shell. We can emulate the similar kind of logging in shell script: http://cubicrace.com/2016/03/efficient-logging-mechnism-in-shell.html

The post has details on introdducing log levels like INFO , DEBUG, ERROR. Tracing details like script entry, script exit, function entry, function exit.

Sample Log:
[image]